# Connect to DB2 using Rational Software Architect (RSA) 9.0

Tags: db2, rational-rsa

I want to know the steps for connecting to DB2 using RSA 9.0. I tried the below steps but I am not able to see any schema after connecting.

- Opened Database development perspective
- Right clicked on Database Connections and clicked on Add Repository
- I have only 2 connection profile types listed -Derby and Generic JDBC (I am not sure whether this is the problem as I dont see DB2)
- I selected Generic JDBC and clicked on Next
- I clicked on new driver configuration add db2 jar (I have tried with db2jcc.jar as well as db2jcc4.jar) and provided the properties
- For driver class, I clicked on Available classes from Jar list and used browse for class option. Here I selected com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
- I have given the connection url in the below format
  jdbc:db2://DBServer:port/DBName
- When I test the connection it shows ping succeeded. But when I try to open the schemas its blank

When I checked with my colleagues, they get DB2 connection profile in RSA. Let me know is there any option for me to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. In IBM installation manager, click on modify and select the language. Then in the list of available components select Data tools. Once installed, DB2 connection profile with IBM data server Driver will be available. Hope this helps.